# Why is Windows 7 rating on my ram less?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, cpu, motherboard

I just upgraded my motherboard and ram. My new motherboard is Esonic G41CMBL with Transcend 4GB DDR3 1333 Ram. My processor is Intel Core 2 Quad q9950. My friend's system has the same configuration but just 2GB DDR3 1333 Ram.

**My Windows 7(x64) System rating for ram HDD and Processor are:**

**Ram** = 5.3

**Processor** = 6.5

**HDD** = 5.3

**My friends Win 7(x32) System Rating:**

**Ram**= 6.7

**Processor** = 6.9

**HDD** = 6.4

Why this discrimination? Thanks in advance

Comment: share the file "Mem.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml" from C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore, this shows why you get this rating

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as a percentage. Your friend has 2GB out of a possible 3.8GB

You, however, have 4GB out of a possible 16GB, or even 32GB depending on your.

Friend = 53%
You = 25% or 12.5% depending on the max ram you could have.

So, that should answer that.